# SVG file render image in smaller size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, svg

I am working for the first time with SVG files. I an able to load SVG files on webview but the images are rendering smaller than the original.
they are getting shrinked by a particular factor...... Is there some solution to my problem??? pls help.

Thank You
Meet bhatha

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the UIWebView to Scale To Fit?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question, but it is solved applying some javascript magic. Please read this post: [UIWebView with just an image that should fit the whole view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667614/uiwebview-with-just-an-image-that-should-fit-the-whole-view)