# Images gets smaller on safari using svg file to load data

Tags: iphone, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SVG file render image in smaller size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570850/svg-file-render-image-in-smaller-size)

Hi,
I am loading data from svg file on the webview in iPhone , but the problem is that images are getting smaller than the original size , when they are displayed on webView.
I am not getting reason that why images are shrinked???

Thanks
Meet B.

Answer (score 0):

try turning off the "scalesPageToFit" property to off, as in:

Yourwebview.scalesPageToFit=FALSE;

Comment: Thankyou....but this does not solve my problem.
Images are still smaller than their original size and text on images is still going out of image boundary.