# making 300x300 webview scale 200x200 image

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am trying to display some images in a UIWebView. they image sizes are 200x200. but I want to make them scale and fill in my 300x300 webview.

I tried All the aspect modes but they do not seem to work.

even `webview.scalesPageToFit = YES;` doesnt work. am I missing something obvious?

Comment: have you taken the delegate of webView.. `webView.delegate = self;` 
?

Comment: @AhmedZ. no I havent, but how would that make a difference?

Comment: It gives you the control over the webView's methods and properties.
Add the delegate line just after you have created or Alloc/init the webView.

Comment: @AhmedZ. but then how would I make it scale my 200x200 image?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
webview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
or
webview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
```

not on my Mac so cannot test, but should work. will update soon

also set,     `webview.autoresizesSubviews = YES;`

**EDIT**:- found a another solution to use HTML to scale the image, have a look the this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667614/uiwebview-with-just-an-image-that-should-fit-the-whole-view)

Comment: Bonnie, I am trying to load NSData in the webview so the HTML solution would not work for me